# Getting a key error while converting npz to csv format

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to convert a `.npz` file to `.csv` format, but it is giving the following key error
 `KeyError: '0 is not a file in the archive'`

I had a sparse matrix which I converted to `.npz` format. I then loaded the npz file using `np.load()`. I tried converting the loaded npz file to csv using `np.savetxt()` but it gives the following error
 `KeyError: '0 is not a file in the archive'`.

What does this key error mean and how to solve it?

I tried the following code:

```
DF = np.load("DF_tfidf.npz")

np.savetxt("DF.csv",DF)
```

Comment: `np.load` gives you a dictionary like object.  The actual arrays are accessed by name, or dictionary `key`.  So it doesn't make sense to simply pass this object to the `savetxt` function.  I suspect you are trying to use these functions without learning what they produce and require.

Comment: If you have created a `scipy` sparse matrix, and saved it with `save_npz` you have added another layer of complexity.  While such a file can be read with `np.load`, you have to understand the save format first.  If instead you use `load_npz`, you get a sparse matrix, just like what you started with.  Saving that to a `csv` text format is different topic.  The simplest would be to convert it to a dense array, with `toarray()`, and write that with `savetxt`.  But if the sparse matrix was at all large, you could end up with a `MemoryError`.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the `csv` to look like?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert NPZ file to csv file. First we need to find out what are the files in NPZ File like below

```
np_Array=np.load('DF_tfidf.npz')
print(np_Array.files)
```

for example if output is like `['arr_0']` for above print
So you need to extract that array and then convert it to csv like below.

```
arr=np_Array.files[0]
np.savetxt("DF.csv", np_Array[arr], delimiter=",")
```

Comment: This ignores the shape and dtype of arrays.  The OP doesn't' understand the content of the npz enough to get meaningful csvs

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem of how to convert npz to csv, but how to properly load the data from the npz, and then save that as csv.  In general a `npz` is a file archive that contains several arrays. A csv on the other is a format for saving one 2d array.

You could, in theory, write each file of the `npz` to its own `csv`.  But if the `npz` saves some complex object, rather than a random set of array, that's probably not what you want to do.  My guess is that you have a `scipy.sparse` matrix (possibly created in the course of some machine learning project).  In that case you should focus on how to write a sparse matrix, or some representation of it, not on converting its `npz` save.

Let's make a scipy sparse matrix and save it:

```
In [45]: from scipy import sparse
In [46]: M = sparse.random(4,4,.2,'csr')
In [47]: M
Out[47]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [48]: M.A
Out[48]: 
array([[0.30442216, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.29783572, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.83881939, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
In [49]: sparse.save_npz('sparse.npz',M)
```

Now load it:

```
In [50]: sparse.load_npz('sparse.npz')
Out[50]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

That's the same thing that we saved.

Now look at it with `np.load`:

```
In [51]: data = np.load('sparse.npz')
In [52]: list(data.keys())
Out[52]: ['indices', 'indptr', 'format', 'shape', 'data']
In [53]: data['indices']
Out[53]: array([0, 0, 2], dtype=int32)
In [54]: data['indptr']
Out[54]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
In [55]: data['format']
Out[55]: array(b'csr', dtype='|S3')
In [56]: data['shape']
Out[56]: array([4, 4])
In [57]: data['data']
Out[57]: array([0.30442216, 0.29783572, 0.83881939])
```

I can save the dense equivalent of this sparse matrix to a `csv` with:

```
In [60]: np.savetxt('sparse.csv', M.A, fmt='%10f',delimiter=',')
In [61]: cat sparse.csv
  0.304422,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000
  0.297836,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000
  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.838819,  0.000000
  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000
```

For a small matrix like this that's no problem.  But often in machine learning the sparse matrix is very large, and `M.A` raises a MemoryError.

I suppose one could try to write a 3 column `csv` with the row,col,data attributes of a `coo` format matrix, the same sort of numbers we get with:

```
In [62]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    0.3044221604204369
  (1, 0)    0.29783571660339536
  (2, 2)    0.8388193913095385
```